What is the role of \tl_to_str:n versus using directly the functions from the l3str module?
Let's say I am creating an expl3 macro:
\cs_new:Nn \my_function:n{
    % Something
}

I have hard time understanding the exact role of \tl_to_str when processing the argument compared to "just" using the functions of the l3str package. What is the difference and when to use \tl_to_str before processing arguments with the l3strmodule? (illustrations showing typical use cases and when there would be a difference between the two approaches would be great).

The str module and \tl_to_str:n work with exactly the same idea - in expl3 terms, a 'string' is a token list made up of category code 12 ('other') tokens other than spaces, which have category code 10 ('space').
The difference is mainly one of convenience/performance. For example, if the user gives us some input #1 which we immediately want to use as a control sequence, and we want to be sure that we use exactly what they provided with no expansion, there is no need to store as a str, rather we can use
\use:c { <some-prefix> \tl_to_str:n {#1} <some-postfix> }

(See the answer by cfr for a more detailed example.)
On the other hand, if we are going to store material anyway and access it several times, then it makes more sense and is clearer in the code if we convert and use str functions
\str_set:Nn \l__mypkg_some_str {#1}
...
\str_case:Nn \l__mypkg_some_str
  {
    { case-one } { action-one }
    ....
  }

One can always use a tl function and convert the argument(s) using \tl_to_str:n to ignore category codes, but this will not help the clarity of the code.
